# Error al instalar NetFramework 4.7.1

Tags: .net, net

Al tratar de instalar cualquier versión del NetFramework a partir de la versión 4.7 me da error, el mensaje dice que el sistema operativo no cumple con los requisitos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ni siquiera en la página de Microsot conseguí la solución, tengo instalado Windows 10 Pro de 64 bits y la versión del NetFramework instalada es la 4.6. Necesito la versión 4.7.1 como mínimo para poder instalar el SourceTree.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una guía paso a paso, ha ayudado a resolver el inconveniente a otros usuarios de Windows 10:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAjnVVH3uLU&ab_channel=ThetaBox

Comment: No hubo suerte Víctor, sigue el problema, gracias por tu aporte